# Working with jQuery scrolltop and fadein/fadeout on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have a div with `position: absolute` inside a relatively positioned parent. I'd like to keep that div positioned on the bottom of it's parent during the `.scroll()` event.

What I'm exactly tried to do here, is when the scrolling starts, `fadeOut()` the `div` then when the scrolling ends fade it in.

My attempt is this:

```
clearTimeout(scroll);
$(Writer).fadeOut('fast');

var scroll = setTimeout(function () {
    $(Writer).css({
        'bottom': 0
    }).fadeIn('slow');
}, 1000);
});
```

Of course this fails miserably.
Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Show some complete example (html, css). Usually use js to show/hide, no need to manipulate with other css params through js for that reason.

Comment: Could you please check my comment on Sangeetas answer

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS. The positioning problem requires this information, otherwise we will just be playing guessing games with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var timer = -1;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(Writer).hide(); // hide instead of fadeOut, as otherwise your users will see your div fading out while scrolling
    timer = setTimeout(function() { $(Writer).fadeIn('slow'); }, 1000);
});
```

**UPDATE**

Check this fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c3z39/ - The demo uses `position: fixed` for the div to demonstrate the concept.

Answer (score 0):

you can try jquery scroll event to do so : on scroll fadeout ur div and fade in as it stops scrolling

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
$(Writer).fadeOut('fast');
$(Writer).css({
        'bottom': 0
    }).fadeIn('slow');
}, 1000);     
    });
```

Comment: still, the div won't be on bottom on the window. What I mean is that I want that div to show as if it had position:fixed and bottom: 0 but with absolute, 0 could mean that it's not visible or it's way above the end of the document.

Comment: with `position: absolute` it uses not window height, but the height of the document, so `bottom:0` will not work as you want. Use `position:fixed` or `position:relative` then.